# .NET datagrid sort incorrectly

Tags: asp.net, .net, sorting, datagrid

I have a .NET DataGrid below, it doesn't sort the column. For example, the sort is like

10
100
21
Even though DataFormatString="{0:N0} has been set, the sort still not work. PLEASE HELP.

```
<asp:DataGrid ID="StatusGrid" CssClass="StatusGrid" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false"
    UseAccessibleHeader="true" OnItemDataBound="StatusGrid_ItemDataBound" OnItemCommand="StatusGrid_ItemCommand">
    <Columns>

            ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left" />
        <asp:BoundColumn DataField="Rating" HeaderText="Performance Rating" ItemStyle-Width="110px"
            ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left" DataFormatString="{0:N0}"/>

    </Columns>
```

Comment: is your data type a string or an int?

Answer (score 1):

This is probably a problem with the data type of the column. It's sorting as if it is a string instead of a number. You were on the right track with your DataFormatString idea but you need to either pass in the data to that column as an int, or implement some custom sorting described here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa984282(v=vs.71).aspx

Comment: It is integer in DB. I don't see apparent cast to string when bounded to the datagrid.